# Webex-BOT, Bot page open event

Tags: python, webex

I need the following:
Send "Welcome" message to user , when the user opens the webex BOT message page.
I can't find any  way for this.
for example: Slack app have event like this:
{"type": "app_home_opened",
"tab": "messages"}

I would like to know, are in webex event type like this?

I read API descriptions and don't find anything like this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.